# why is 0-61 unit of second in POSIXct

Tags: r

when you search `Date-Time Classes` in R manual ,you can get

```
sec

    0–61: seconds
```

why the seconds is not between `0-59` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I recall this is for leap second adjustments.

Checking `NEWS.*` real quick I find eg

```
o   .leap.seconds and the internal adjustment code now know about
the 23rd leap second on 2005-12-31: the internal code uses a
run-time test to see if the OS does.
```